# Does using a Broom of Flying cost your movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, movement, flight, vehicles

[Broom of Flying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4597-broom-of-flying)

> This wooden broom, which weighs 3 pounds, functions like a mundane broom until you stand astride it and speak its Command word. It then hovers beneath you and can be ridden in the air. It has a Flying speed of 50 feet. It can carry up to 400 pounds, but its Flying speed becomes 30 feet while carrying over 200 pounds. The broom stops hovering when you land.

Does moving using a Broom of Flying cost your movement, or only the broom's? For example, if you had a walking speed of 30 feet, and you just used all 50 feet of movement available to the broom just off the ground, could you immediately dismount it then walk another 30 feet?